# Can these determinants be analytically continued?

Tags: matrices, number-theory, riemann-zeta

Let $A$ be the matrix:

$$A(n,k): \text{If } k \text{ divides } n \text{ then } \frac{k}{n^{\frac{1}{4} (3+2 i t)}} \text{ else } 0 $$

and let $B$ be the matrix:

$$B(n,k): \text{If } k \text{ divides } n \text{ then } \frac{\mu (k)}{n^{\frac{1}{4} (3+2 i t)}} \text{ else } 0 $$

where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function.

Then let $d$ be the determinant of the matrix product of matrix $A$ times the transposed matrix $B$, plus the identity matrix (as in linear algebra) :

$$d(t) = \left|A.B^{\mathsf{T}}+\text{IdentityMatrix}\right|$$

The plot of the real part of the determinant $d(t)$ of the symmetric $17$x$17$ matrix looks like this:

[image: plot of determinant]

where the black lines are at the Riemann zeta zeros on the critical line.

(I don't have the computing power to compute larger matrices than this.)

Compare this to the partial sums of the Möbius function times some constant plotted in red on the critical line, superimposed with the imposed with the determinant d(t) plotted in blue:

[image: superimposed Moebius function sum determinant]

where the partial sum of the Möbius function is:

$$2.3 \; \Re\left(\sum _{n=1}^{\text{17}} \frac{\mu (n)}{n^{\frac{1}{2}+i t}}\right)$$

The constant 2.3 is not any specific number it is just there to make the height of the plots match somewhat.

One could then say that the determinant is equal to the characteristic polynomial of $A.B^{\mathsf{T}}$ evaluated at $x=-1$.

> Because the reciprocal of Riemann zeta: $$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$ is the analytical continuation
>   of the Möbius function sum, can the determinant $d(t)$ be analytically
>   continued to the critical line?

Or am I asking for too much since this construction, the determinant $d(t)$, is a bit arbitrary?

Associated Mathematica program:

```
(*Mathematica 8 start*)
nnn = 17;
Monitor[g = Table[Clear[s, x, t, nn, n, k];
   nn = ii;
   A = Table[
     Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, N[k/n^(1/4 (3 + 2 I t))], 0], {k, 1, 
       nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
   B = Table[
     Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, MoebiusMu[k]/n^N[(1/4 (3 + 2 I t))], 
       0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
   d = Det[A.Transpose[B] + IdentityMatrix[nnn]];
   Show[Plot[Re[d], {t, 0, 60}],
    Graphics[
     Table[Line[{{Im[ZetaZero[n]], -2}, {Im[ZetaZero[n]], 2}}], {n, 1,
        12}]], ImageSize -> Large], {ii, nnn, nnn}], ii]
g2 = Plot[
   2.3*Re[Sum[MoebiusMu[n]/n^(1/2 + I*t), {n, 1, nnn}]], {t, 0, 60}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[g[[1]], g2]
(*Mathematica 8 end*)
```

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1979866/8530

Comment: Adapt [what I wrote there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1851637/276986) about the determinant of the Redheffer matrix. In particular you have to write explicitly the value of $(AB)_{n,k}$, you'll obtain a triangular matrix whose determinant is the product of the diagonal values (and it works for many of your other questions involving some matrices)